# is it possible to have a mute button using the custom soundcloud player widget api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundcloud

I would like to add in a mute button to my soundcloud player http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/custom-player but I can't see anything in the script or documentation to be able to do this. Is there any way possible of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the current volume with this method api_getVolume() and 
after you can set it to zero with this method api_setVolume(0).

As you saved the current volume, you can test it back after... All the 
methods are here: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/widget

You can have a look on this website if you want some inspiration: 
http://popcornjs.org/code/players/soundcloud/popcorn.soundcloud.html

Comment: that isnt the custom player but the javascript api